# If $f\in L^{1}([0,1])$ and $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f$ for $x\in[0,1],$ prove $F$ is absolutely continuous from the definition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> $\textbf{The Problem:}$ Let $f\in L^{1}([0,1])$ and define
>   $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f\quad(x\in[0,1]).$$
>   Prove directly from the definition of absolute continuity that $F$ is absolutely continuous.

$\textbf{My Thoughts:}$ Since $f\in L^1([0,1])$ we have that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that
$$\int_{E}|f|<\varepsilon\quad\text{whenever }E\subset[0,1]\text{ and }m(E)<\delta.$$
Using the above it follows that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that
\begin{align*}\sum^{n}_{j=1}|F(b_j)-F(a_j)|&=\sum^{n}_{j=1}\Bigg|\int_{0}^{b_j}f-\int_{0}^{a_j}f\Bigg|\\
&\leq\sum^{n}_{j=1}\int_{a_j}^{b_j}|f|\\
&<\frac{\varepsilon}{n}\\&<\varepsilon
\end{align*}
whenever $\sum^{n}_{j=1}(b_j-a_j)<\delta$ and the intervals $(a_j,b_j),j,=1\dots,n$ are disjoint. Therefore $F$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$.

---

Could anyone check if my proof is correct?

Thank you for your time and appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Well, your starting postulate in itself is already 80% of the job done. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213762/if-f-in-l10-1-and-fx-int-0xf-quadx-in0-1-prove-f-is-abs

Comment: How did you get $\dfrac{\varepsilon}{n}$? Isn't it $n\varepsilon$?

Comment: @JohnThompson You're right, thanks for noting that typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof: Define $E:=\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=1}^n (a_k,b_k)$.\begin{align*}\sum^{n}_{j=1}|F(b_j)-F(a_j)|&=\sum^{n}_{j=1}\Bigg|\int_{0}^{b_j}f-\int_{0}^{a_j}f\Bigg|\\
&\leq\sum^{n}_{j=1}\int_{a_j}^{b_j}|f|\\
&=\displaystyle\int_E|f|\\&<\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
since $m(E)=\sum^{n}_{j=1}(b_j-a_j)<\delta$.