# If $f\in L^{1}([0,1]\times[0,1])$ and $F(x)=\int_{[0,x]\times[0,x]} f$ for$x\in [0,1]$, prove $F$ is absolutely continuous from the definition.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

I've seen there was a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213762/if-f-in-l10-1-and-fx-int-0xf-for-x-in0-1-prove-f-is-ab).

This question was only for $L^{1}[0,1]$. I want to extend it to $L^{1}([0,1]\times[0,1])$.

The question is:

> If $f\in L^{1}([0,1]\times[0,1])$ and for $x\in [0,1]$, $$F(x)=\int_{[0,x]\times[0,x]} f.$$  Prove that $F$ is absolutely continuous and express the derivative of $F$ using $f$.

There must be difference of solution. For example, $$\int_{[0,b_k]\times[0,b_k]} f - \int_{[0,a_k]\times[0,a_k]} f \neq \int_{[a_k,b_k]\times[a_k,b_k]} f$$

But $$\int_{[0,b_k]} f - \int_{[0,a_k]} f = \int_{[a_k,b_k]} f$$

Could someone give me a hint to solve this problem?

Comment: What did you try? [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I tried to separate 3 areas. [0,a_k]*[a_k,b_k], [a_k,b_k]*[0,a_k],[a_k,b_k]*[a_k,b_k] to calculate the difference of two intergrals.

Comment: @Hobby I added a hint as an answer. Did you try to look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int_{\left[0, x\right]\times \left[0, x\right]} f(t, s) \mathrm dt \mathrm ds\\
&= \int_0^x \int_0^t f(t, s) \mathrm ds \mathrm dt + \int_0^x \int_t^x f(t, s) \mathrm ds \mathrm dt\\
&= \int_0^x \int_0^t f(t, s) \mathrm ds \mathrm dt + \int_0^x \int_0^s f(t, s) \mathrm dt \mathrm ds\\
&= \int_0^x \left(\int_0^t \left(f(t, s) + f(s, t)\right)\mathrm  ds\right)\mathrm dt
\end{align}

So $F$ is absolute continuous and $$F'(x) = \int_{0}^x \left(f(x, t) + f(t, x)\right)\mathrm d t$$